# How can I implement an array list to this html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently just started getting into html and was wondering how can I implement the following code and be more efficient and use an arrayList.

```
<!-- 
This was me just trying to play around with arrays and elements
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("[id^=pop]");
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elements);
-->
var p = $("[id^=pop]");
var position = p.position();
$("[id^=pop]").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).animate({
        width: "400px",
        height: "400px",
        top: position.top*.7,
        left: position.left*.7
    }, 150);

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px",
        top: position.top,
        left: position.left
    }, 150);

});
```

As of now, when an image id equals pop0, and then another one equal pop1. They both will animate to the first image's height and width. How can I use an array so every img has its own position and won't be based off the first image that is loaded but rather their own top and left coordinates?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: your selector already return an 'array' of object, move the position var inside the function or use $(this).offset().top or left respectively

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to move your `position` variable from outside of your hover event handlers to inside your hover event handlers. This will set the context to the currently hovered item.

Currently your `p` variable stores an array of all elements beginning with an ID that starts with `pop`. Then you are storing a reference to the first element's position and never updating by setting the value of `position` outside of your hover event handlers.

Here's an example with a small bit of caching so you're not always querying the DOM.

```
var $pop = $( '[id^=pop]' );

$pop.hover( function hoverIn() {

    var $this = $( this ),
        pos   = $this.position();

    $this
        .css( 'cursor', 'pointer' ) // <= Possibly do this via CSS.
        .animate( {
            width: '400px',
            height: '400px',
            top: pos.top * 0.7,
            left: pos.left * 0.7
        }, 150 );

}, function hoverOut() {

    var $this = $( this ),
        pos   = $this.position();

    $this.animate( {
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left
    }, 150 );

} );
```